# State Machine Rails 4 doesn't back to the initial state

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, state-machine

I need a little help with state machine because I'm working with rails 4  I have a initial state called in_analysis and other states called approved and reject and the states approved and reject works fine I don't have problem for pass through to the states, but I can't back to the initial state called in_analysis, here is my code:

**app/models/profile.rb**

```
state_machine :state, :initial => :in_analysis do
 state :in_analysis, :approved, :rejected

 state :approved do
  validates :name, presence: true
 end

 event :approved do
  transition in_analysis: :approved
 end

 event :reject do
  transition in_analysis: :rejected
  transition approved: :rejected
 end
end
```

and in my controller I have this:

```
  def update
   @profile.state = :in_analysis

   @profile = current_user.profile

  respond_to do |format|
   if @profile.update(profile_params)
    format.html { redirect_to edit_profile_path(@profile), notice:     t(:update, scope: [:messages, :controllers, :profiles, :successfully]) }
    format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: edit_profile_path(@profile) }
   else
    format.html { render :edit }
    format.json { render json: @profile.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
 end
end
```

so my goal is when the profile is updated the state back to the initial "in_analysis" but I don't know why doesn't work because the another state works well.

Thanks for the time ! regards !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your `state_machine` is correct, the only place that you might be doing wrong is

```
@profile.state = :in_analysis

@profile = current_user.profile
```

You assign the `state` to `:in_analysis` then you actually assign `@profile` to old `current_user.profile` which is fetched from database thus your assignment to `:in_analysis` is discarded.

You can try to swap the two line:

```
@profile = current_user.profile
@profile.state = :in_analysis
```

Comment: Wow thank you is that, I just needed to swap my lines !

Comment: If my answer resolves your problem, please mark it as accepted answer so other people might know :)